How to compile IUP/CD/IM under mingw
I cannot find a detailed guide on how to compile IM/CD/IUP under Mingw64. The instructions in the website do not help.
I used tecmake and mingw32-make to no avail.
Is it still supported?
I get
c:\work\luvit\cd>cd src

c:\work\luvit\cd\src>tecmake all-gcc_dll
The system cannot find the path specified.
c:\work\luvit\tecmake\tecmakewin.mak:1835: dep/cd.dep.dllw6: No such file or directory
mingw32-make: *** [c:\work\luvit\tecmake\tecmakewin.mak:1814: dep/cd.dep.dllw6] Error 255
The system cannot find the path specified.
c:\work\luvit\tecmake\tecmakewin.mak:1835: dep/cd.dep.dllw6_64: No such file or directory
mingw32-make: *** [c:\work\luvit\tecmake\tecmakewin.mak:1814: dep/cd.dep.dllw6_64] Error 255

